# Asterisk and AddPac AP 100 connectivity

Tags: voip, asterisk

I have analog phone connected to AddPac gateway. I am trying to connect it to asterisk through SIP. Here is the configuration (relevant lines):

sip.conf

```
[user]
type=friend
context=office
host=192.168.31.11
secret=user
username=user
dtfmmode=auto
```

extensions.conf

```
[office]
exten => 20,1, Dial(SIP/user)
```

AddPac have web interface, so I have configured it to use SIP, set SIP server IP address, username, password.

when I execute `sip show peers` I get this:

```
Name/username              Host            Dyn Nat ACL Port     Status
user/user                 192.168.31.11               5060     Unmonitored
```

By the way, what does `unmonitored` mean?

Ping is successful. I think I am missing something obvious here. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed this line:

```
dtfmmode=auto
```

and everything started to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to monitor if the sip peer is still alive then add;

```
qualify=yes
```

or specify timeout(in ms) like so;

```
qualify=100
```